# using variables created in function

Tags: php, scope

I'm using simple html DOM and extracting two links from website.

```
function get_links($website) {
$html = file_get_html($website);   
$img = $html->find('div.entry img',0)->src;  
$url = $html->find('div.entry a',0)->href;}
```

how do I use $img and $url after I run function get_links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options.  The first is to return them:

```
function get_links($website) {
    $html = file_get_html($website);   
    $img = $html->find('div.entry img',0)->src;  
    $url = $html->find('div.entry a',0)->href;
    return array('img' => $img, 'url' => $url);
}
```

You can only return one value from a function, so you have to make an array.

The other option is to take arguments by reference:

```
function get_links($website, &$img, &$url) {
    $html = file_get_html($website);   
    $img = $html->find('div.entry img',0)->src;  
    $url = $html->find('div.entry a',0)->href;
}
```

When you call this, you can then provide two values, which will contain the values:

```
get_links($someurl, $image, $url);
echo $image; // echoes the image source
echo $url; // echoes the url
```

I expect the first technique (the array) would be the simpler.

You have other options: you could make `$img` and `$url` global. This is a Bad Idea. You could also define `get_links` as an anonymous function and use the `use` keyword, but this is less useful, I think. You could also encapsulate the function in an object:

```
class Links {
    public $url;
    public $img;

    function __construct($website) 
        $html = file_get_html($website);   
        $this->img = $html->find('div.entry img',0)->src;  
        $this->url = $html->find('div.entry a',0)->href;
    }
}

// elsewhere
$links = new Links($someurl);
$links->img;
$links->url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return them as an array:

```
return array(
    'img'  => $img,
    'url'    => $url
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways:

- return them to caller (as an array)
- declare them outside the function in a different scope optic
- declare them globals
- so on

Consider the solution that fit better to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is only partially complete.  You need to return those values to the calling origin for use there. When returning multiple values from a function, I prefer to return it as an associative array.

```
function get_links($website) {
   $html = file_get_html($website);   
   $img = $html->find('div.entry img',0)->src;  
   $url = $html->find('div.entry a',0)->href;}
   $results = array('img' => $img, 'url' => $url);
   return $results;
}
```